# Tornado Escape Pound # character

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-services, url, tornado

I am writing a program/ service that handle text and its attributes.
localhost:8000/title?img=img_url.jpg&text_color=#FF0000

and In my handler I have something like:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/title_overlay", MainHandler),
    ])

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
         return True

    def get(self):
        image_url = self.get_argument("img", None, True)
        image_local_file = 'image' + "_" + image_url.split('/')[-1]
        urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, image_local_file)
        text_color = self.get_argument('text_color', '', True)
    .....
    ..... 
    .....
```

I'm unable to get text_color value ie.#FF0000. Extracting imgurl works but not text_color. 
Does this have to do something with the # character. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because the portion after '#' is called the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), which the browser does not even send to the server when it fetches the URL. In order to encode a color in your URL you'll have to omit the '#' character, or URL-encode it:

`text_color=%23FF0000`

Comment: Is there any way I can get that ?

Comment: The browser does not even send the fragment to the server when it fetches the URL.